# Placing an image in between header words

Tags: html, css, image, header

I was wondering if anyone could help me. I am trying to place an image in between two words in my header. e.g FirstName (Image) LastName. However, every time I try the image shifts the words so that everything is stacking and I want it horizontal. Can anyone help with this? 
What I have done so far:

```html
<div class="horizontal">
  <h1>FN LN</h1>
  <!-- box-b -->
  <div class="box-b">
    <img src="Images/Triangle.png" alt="Logo mark">
  </div>
  <!-- /box-b -->
</div>
```

So I'd want the image to move up between the two words.

Comment: Perhaps try a HTML table?

Comment: What about `<h1>FN <img src="..."> LN</h1>`?

Comment: Add an attribute to `<img>` tag like `style="display:inline"`. If it won't work, try with CSS box model, setting appropriate margin & padding. I think Firefox developer tools might be of some help...

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images are [inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2402773/766958) elements that should not 'break' your text onto multiple lines, if the issue is alignment, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32032259/766958) you can use `vertical-align` in CSS to align your image inline with your text.

Like what @Psi mentioned:

```
<h1>FN <img src="..."> LN</h1>
```

Should work fine then tweak the CSS for alignment